# VBA Type Mismatch of the same functions in different workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having an issue resolving a Type mismatch when running the same code in a different Workbook. Lets say Workbook 1 is the original workbook, and Workbook 2 is the new workbook.

Both Workbook 1 & 2 have the same code (below) where the `Listbox_Refresh` sub calls the `GetAccountRef()` Function. The code runs good in Workbook 1 but has a type mismatch in Workbook 2 and I cannot figure out why.

I've checked the **VarTypes** of `GetAccountRef()` in both Workbooks and they are different.

For Workbook 1

- This results in 8204 (vbArray + Variant) as expected:

  ```
  Debug.Print VarType(GetAccountRef())
  ```
- This results in 8 (String) as expected:

  ```
  Debug.Print VarType(GetAccountRef(0))
  ```

For Workbook 2

- This results in 0 (Empty):

  ```
  Debug.Print VarType(GetAccountRef())
  ```
- This results in Error Type Mismatch:

  ```
  Debug.Print VarType(GetAccountRef(0))
  ```

The function I am trying to run is:

```
Function GetAccountRef() As Variant
On Error Resume Next

Dim Cell As Range
Dim Row_I As Range
Set Row_I = Sheet5.Range("9:9")    '<- ERROR: This range does not contain "Date"

Dim Counter As Integer
Counter = 0
Dim Date_Ref() As Variant


For Each Cell In Row_I
    If Cell = "Date" Then

        ReDim Preserve Date_Ref(Counter)
        Date_Ref(Counter) = Cell.Address
        GetAccountRef = Date_Ref

        Counter = Counter + 1
    End If
Next Cell


On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

And I'm trying to utilize this function in a `For` loop like so:

```
    Dim ListedBnk As Variant
    For Each ListedBnk In GetAccountRef()
        ListedBnk = Replace(ListedBnk, "9", "7")
        .ComboBox1.AddItem Range(ListedBnk)
        .ComboBox2.AddItem Range(ListedBnk)

    Next ListedBnk
```

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the On Error Resume Next - where and how does it fail?

Comment: Since the value of GetAccountRef ultimately draws from the Row_I range, I suspect that range is empty in Workbook2.  In any event, I agree with the comment above that the error trapping should be removed and you should step through the code to see exactly where it fails.

Comment: @TonyM yes it was indeed this, wish I would have saw your comment earlier!

Answer (score 0):

Your Function has some mistake.

```
Function GetAccountRef() As Variant
On Error Resume Next

Dim Cell As Range
Dim Row_I As Range
Set Row_I = Sheet5.Range("9:9")    'TFSA Tracker ONLY

Dim Counter As Integer
Counter = 0
Dim Date_Ref() As Variant


For Each Cell In Row_I
    If Cell = "Date" Then

        ReDim Preserve Date_Ref(Counter)
        Date_Ref(Counter) = Cell.Address
        Counter = Counter + 1
    End If
Next Cell

        GetAccountRef = Date_Ref '<~~ At this moved.
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

and your Sheet module

```
Sub test()
    Dim ListedBnk As Variant
    Dim myArray As Variant

    myArray = GetAccountRef

    With ActiveSheet
        .ComboBox1.Clear
        .ComboBox2.Clear
    'For Each ListedBnk In GetAccountRef()
    For Each ListedBnk In myArray
        ListedBnk = Replace(ListedBnk, "9", "7")
        .ComboBox1.AddItem Sheet5.Range(ListedBnk)
        .ComboBox2.AddItem Sheet5.Range(ListedBnk)

    Next ListedBnk
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Moving GetAccountRef = Date_Ref  to the end of the function did fix the VarType issue and recognized VarType(GetAccountRef()) as 8204 but could not recognize VarType(GetAccountRef(0)) as an array - it displayed 0.

The sheet module change gave a loop error since GetAccountRef() was empty. 

Thanks for your comment, I have found my mistake! Will post it below.. it is quite silly..

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake, function looks for the identifier in a range that does not contain it. Thanks to everyone in who posted a comment/solution!

Improvements would be to write dynamic identifiers that adjust the range when Rows/Columns are added.

Function:

```
Function GetAccountRef() As Variant
On Error Resume Next

Dim Cell As Range
Dim Row_I As Range
Set Row_I = Sheet5.Range(**"10:10"**)    '<- previous range("9:9") did not contain the *identifier "Date"*, it was in row 10.

Dim Counter As Integer
Counter = 0
Dim Date_Ref() As Variant


For Each Cell In Row_I
    If Cell = "Date" Then

        ReDim Preserve Date_Ref(Counter)
        Date_Ref(Counter) = Cell.Address
        GetAccountRef = Date_Ref

        Counter = Counter + 1

    End If
Next Cell



On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Sheet Sub:

```
   With Activesheet
        Dim ListedBnk As Variant
        For Each ListedBnk In GetAccountRef()
            ListedBnk = Range(Replace(ListedBnk, "10", "8"))    '<- Also needs to refer to **Row 10**
            .ComboBox1.AddItem ListedBnk
            .ComboBox2.AddItem ListedBnk

        Next ListedBnk
    End With
```